# New popup with hints after pressing a key

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a popup, where I will can choose one of items. While typing, these hints should be filtered.  I created new window but I can not type, when this window is opened. When I click on text field, the window closes.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: It should looks like this]

Comment: It would be great if you can share your code to analyze it.

Comment: Agreed. Debugging invisible code is quite difficult.

Comment: Maybe you want an [Auto complete JComoboBox](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=B8HGU4GiGISB8gWSyIDoCA#q=site:stackoverflow.com+jcombobox+autocomplete)

Comment: @peeskillet 
Thats it! Thanks :)